# Python. Define "attribute initial method"

Tags: python

I have:

```
class C:
    aaa=2


class B:
     def __init__ (self,name):
         self.name
         self.value
```

How can i define class `C` so when i dynamically set attribute to instance it make that attribute instance of class `B`. And attribute name of class `B` have to have attribute `name` equal string of name of that new attribute in class `C` and attribute `value` of `B` instance  have to have value what set in new attribute in instance of class `C`.

Have to give me that result:

```
>> c=C()
>> c.whatever= 'strinstrinsstring'
>> isinstance(c.whatever,B)
True
>> c.whatever.value
'strinstrinsstring'
>>c.whatever.name
'whatever'
```

Comment: I would like to encourage you to work on the clarity of your question.

Comment: Sorry, i even didn't know what world clarity mean.  :) But I think you can get clarity from a code... :) But anyway tanks for pushing me to learn English )...

Comment: Why would you want that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just smartly override `__setattr__`.  If you want to do it only for a specific attribute, then put in a special case for the attribute name that you want to look for:

```
>>> class B:
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value


>>> class C:
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name == 'makeMeB':
            newb = B(name, value)
            self.__dict__[name] = newb
        else:
            self.__dict__[name] = value

>>> c = C()
>>> c.makeMeB = 'foo'
>>> isinstance(c.makeMeB, B)
True
>>> c.makeMeB.name
'makeMeB'
>>> c.makeMeB.value
'foo'
>>> c.blah = 'foo'
>>> isinstance(c.blah, B)
False
```

If you want it for *every* attribute, just forget the `if` and it'll do it for everything:

```
>>> class B:
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value


>>> class C:
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        attr_as_b = B(name, value)
        self.__dict__[name] = attr_as_b

>>> c = C()
>>> c.makeMeB = 'foo'
>>> isinstance(c.makeMeB, B)
True
>>> c.makeMeB.name
'makeMeB'
>>> c.makeMeB.value
'foo'
>>> c.amIalsoB = 'well?'
>>> isinstance(c.amIalsoB, B)
True
>>> c.amIalsoB.name
'amIalsoB'
>>> c.amIalsoB.value
'well?'
```

Comment: I think this is the right idea, but the OP wants *all* dynamically set attributes of `class C` to be instances of `class B`, not just some with a special name. -- so no `if name == 'makeMeB':` required.

Comment: Yeah that wasn't clear from the question, so I went with the slightly more specific version that would be easier to scale back from.  I'll edit the other one in as well.

Comment: But don’t use `__dict__` directly, use `super(C, self).__setattr__` instead (and then you would have to use new-style classes via subclassing object too, what I would recommend anyway). Otherwise this may break `__setattr__` customizations of superclasses one may use.

Comment: Yeah I didn't use the new-style classes because the OP didn't.  As-is there's nothing to `super`.  Good advice though, +1

Comment: @Pol: OP means "original poster", the originator of a particular thread.

Comment: What gonna happen if i set my predefined attribute 'aaa'? Which has init value '2'? Does it become instance of B?

Comment: @Pol: While you could easily answer this for yourself. I'd like to point why the answer is no, `aaa` will not be affected. There *two* reasons for this: one is because it was created by the `class C` statement's execution, and two, even if it was created later outside of the statement, it's an attribute of the `C` class itself, not instances of that class which are what the `__setattr__()` affects.

Answer (score 1):

This is a horrible thing to do, because it changes what attributes mean!

Why not just look at the `__dict__` of `c`:

```
>>> class C(object):
...     pass
...
>>> c = C()
>>> c.spam = 'ham'
>>> c.__dict__
{'spam': 'ham'}
```

Comment: Ah but you can :)  See my answer!

Comment: @Daniel: oh, I see! I didn't parse the question properly. What a nasty thing to do :p